# Installing Kali Linux and Removing Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali-linux, dual-boot, grub

I am planning to Install Kali Linux and Remove Ubuntu.

My question is, I already have the Ubuntu's GRUB.  So when installing Kali Linux, I am going to overwrite the Ubuntu partition.  But do I also install Kali Linux's GRUB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing to use the whole disk while installing Kali will erase everything on the disk and install itself. It'll of course install a bootloader, GRUB.

Comment: Kali's installation actually gives you the choice of whether or not you want to install GRUB.  So I am guessing I will put Yes to that part of the installation?

Comment: Exactly, choose yes and go on.